# Navigation Arrow like Apple Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, google-maps

I am trying to create a custom navigation arrow (I don't know the exact name) without using apple or google maps. Navigation arrow in my meaning is the green thing that rotates with the phone.

An example of what I call "navigation arrow":

[image]

I know this uses the `UIAccelerometer` but still I have not a clue what I need to do.
So the question is, Can anyone give me some pointers to create this without using maps? Is there any tutorials out there or a Github project? Or does anyone knows the actual name of this?

Comment: you create a custom annotation view and set its image ;) the rest is.. not even math

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CLLocationManager` to obtain `CLLocation` instances which, in turn, have `course` property. Or maybe try to use magnetometerData of `CMMotionManager`.